# How to change Android SDK temp download directory?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

First off I want to say that I'm not trying to change where software should "look," for the SDK. I already did that and it works fine.

I am trying to update the SDK tools through Android Studio and even though I already have the SDK and other tools installed on a larger secondary "E:/" drive that's 4tb, Android Studio insists on downloading something more than 60gb of files onto my (already almost full) 120gb SSD boot drive where Android Studio is installed.

The folders that it's downloading are:

```
C:\users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Temp\PackageOperation##
```

It only said it was going to take 14GB before I started downloading which makes it all the more frustrating. It's still downloading as I post this, and it's only about 1/4 of the way done but I have to go to work. I'm worried it's going to run out of space and not be able to finish. Is there any way to tell Android Studio to download these to my other HDD?

**Update:** It went to about 70GB and left me with only 1GB of free space before it started deleting the files and freeing up space. It ended up finishing, but I don't know if this was a coincidence or not. It's still too close for comfort so if anyone could help that would be fantastic